# "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '}

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

Using Retrofit  Request.

Post Method for
//SignUp

```
    @POST("UIGAttendance/UserRegistration")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<RegistrationListApi> signUp(@Field("CNIC") String CNIC ,@Field("FullName") String FullName,
                                     @Field("address") String address, @Field("Email") String Email,
                                     @Field("Mobile") String Mobile, @Field("Username") String Username,
                                     @Field("Password") String Password, @Field("HostName") String HostName);
```

postman :
http://202.69.38.84/UIGAttendance/API/UIGAttendance/UserRegistration?CNIC=*****-1890196-5&FullName=Test User&address=Lahore Pakistan&Email=Test@gmail.com&Mobile=03344152669&Username=TestUSer&Password=TestPassword&HostName=Test Host

Error:
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://202.69.38.84/UIGAttendance/API/UIGAttendance/UserRegistration'."}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz5Uy.png)

Comment: Check the response of your api in postman

Comment: {
    " User Registration": [
        {
            "ResponseCode": "01",
            "ResponseDesc": "User Already Exists"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Response is okie

Comment: Upload image of postman want to cross check

Comment: added!! just click the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use query params In postman, but use formurlencoded in the code

Comment: used @Query instead of  Field and foformurlencoded

Comment: getting the   response .!! Thanks